# Duplicate variable name warning in Python

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I have developed a code for an optimization problem in Python and defined a binary variable in the model. Then I used the Docplex module to solve the model through the Cplex engine. I've mentioned a part of the code as follows.

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
model = Model(name='Logistics')

T = 3
A = 3
I = [3200, 2600, 2530]

LI = [[[model.binary_var(name="LI" + str(t) + str(i) + str(a)) for a in
range(A)] for i in range(I[t])] for t in range(T)]
```

After running the code, I got an optimal solution depicted below.

- Model: Reverse Logistics
- number of variables: 24990

  - binary=24990, integer=0, continuous=0
- number of constraints: 0

  - linear=0
- parameters: defaults
- objective: maximize
- problem type is: MILP
- profit: 2499000.0

But I got some warning messages once I tried to run the code for A = 11. As you can see, I've mentioned some of these warning messages. These messages appeared before the optimal solution.

.
.
.
.
.
.
Warning: Duplicate variable name: LI225110 already used for docplex.mp.Var(type=B,name='LI225110')

Warning: Duplicate variable name: LI225210 already used for docplex.mp.Var(type=B,name='LI225210')

- Model: Reverse Logistics
- number of variables: 91630

  - binary=91630, integer=0, continuous=0
- number of constraints: 0

  - linear=0
- parameters: defaults
- objective: maximize
- problem type is: MILP
- profit: 9163000.0

I want to know what these warnings are for and how should I fix them. I need your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names should probably be unique.

A simple solution could be to add the `t`, `i` and `a` variable into the `name`:

```
LI = [[[model.binary_var(name=f"LI_{t}_{i}_{a}") for ...
```